# Add 2nd column index to pandas dataframe using another dataframe column

Tags: dataframe, indexing

I have these 2 dataframes

```
edfmonthtradedays
Out[57]: 
Instrument  AAPL.O  AMZN.O  FB.OQ  GOOG.OQ  GOOGL.OQ  BHP.AX JPM.N  MSFT.O  \
Date                                                                         
2016-04-30      21      21     21       21        21     21     21      21   
2016-05-31      21      21     21       21        21     21     21      21   
2016-06-30      22      22     22       22        22     22     22      22
```

and

```
rics
Out[60]: 
          0   1
0    AAPL.O  US
1    MSFT.O  US
2    AMZN.O  US
3    BHP.AX  AU
```

I am trying to add a second column index to df1 using column[1] in df2, such that AAPL.O column would also have 'US' as a column index, BHP.AX would have 'AU', etc? I am new to python and programming but have tried for some time to get this working without luck.

I have tried,

```
dfmonthtradedays.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(dfmonthtradedays.columns, rics[1].tolist())
```

number columns in df1 = number rows in df2

Regards

Comment: You mention that you have tried something, could you post it here (even if it is not working)?  Posting just a question without showing what you have tried is frowned upon in StackOverflow, and your question risks getting down-voted or closed otherwise.

Comment: apologies. have edited question.